# How to remove jquery-1.12.4.js file from wicket-core jar while maven build

Tags: security, deployment, maven-3, wicket-7

In our project developed based on wicket framework, that used wicket-core jar and other transitive dependencies.
Here project configured with jquery-3.6.0.js that the facilitate of wicket framework so that won't problem.

Here wicket-core jar have all jquery file as below images
[image]
As per security perpective, vulnerable resource won't be delivered to client so wicket-core's resource provoke the security vunerability.

Any possibilities to remove vunerable resources (jquery .js files) while maven build happens....

I tried with maven-shade-plugin but couldn't get correct way of configuration this.

I need solution expected whether extension of maven-shade-plugin configuration or anyother ways to remove those js files while maven build